# How can I make that the object will scale automatic up/down nonstop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I'm using the F key to make it scale up or down.
But I want to add another method for example AutoScaling that when calling it in Update it will scale up first once finished scaling up it will scale down and then up again and so no nonstop.

The Scaling script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public GameObject lookAtTarget;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool scalingHasFinished = false;

    public void Inits()
    {
        scalingHasFinished = false;
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, Camera objectToScaleCamera)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            if (scaleUp)
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }
            else
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(objectToScaleCamera.transform.forward);//SwitchCameras.GetCurrentCamera().transform.forward);//Camera.main.transform.forward);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        scalingHasFinished = true;
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, float rotationSpeed)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            targetObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the script that use the scaling :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsManipulation : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera
    public Camera playerCamera;

    //Scaling
    private bool canScale = true;
    private Scaling scaling;

    //Lights
    public DimLights dimlights;
    private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

    //Colors
    private Colors colors;

    //Rotating
    private bool stopRotation = false;
    private Rotating rotating;

    private void Start()
    {
        scaling = GetComponent<Scaling>();
        scaling.Inits();

        colors = GetComponent<Colors>();
        colors.Start();

        rotating = GetComponent<Rotating>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerCamera != null)
        {
            //Scaling
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && canScale == true)
            {
                Scaling();
            }
        }

        //Rotate
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
            rotating.keyPressed = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            rotating.keyPressed = false;
        }

        if (!rotating.keyPressed && !scaling.scaleUp && rotating.rotateBack == false
            && DetectInteractable.detected == false)
        {
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerCamera.transform.forward);
        }

        if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && !scaling.scaleUp && stopRotation == false)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
        }
    }

    public void Scaling()
    {
        //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
        scaling.scaleUp = !scaling.scaleUp;

        //Stop old coroutine
        if (scaling.scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaling.scaleCoroutine);

        if (lightCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);

        //Scale  up
        if (scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            rotating.rotateBack = false;
            scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.maxSize, scaling.duration, playerCamera));
            if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(1, scaling.duration));
        }

        //Scale Down
        else
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            rotating.rotateBack = true;
            scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.minSize, scaling.duration, playerCamera));
            if (dimlights.lightsOnOff == false)
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(0, scaling.duration)); ;
        }
    }
}
```

And in third script I want to call a method that will be in the ObjectsManipulation script maybe the same method Scaling maybe he will get a bool and if the bool is true make it scaling up/down automatic if it's not true make it use a key.

This is the script for testing the Scaling :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScalingTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    ObjectsManipulation om;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        om.Scaling();
    }
}
```

For example in the Update maybe to do : om.Scaling(false); for using the F key and om.Scaling(true); for automatic.

Update of what I have tried :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueIndex;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int conversationIndex;

    private bool triggered = false;
    private bool activateButton = false;
    private DialogueManager dialoguemanager;
    private bool startDialogue = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        dialogueIndex = 0;
        dialoguemanager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversation(int index)
    {
        this.conversationIndex = index;

        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[index].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < conversations[index].Dialogues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (triggered == false)
                {
                    if (dialoguemanager != null)
                    {
                        dialoguemanager.StartDialogue(conversations[index].Dialogues[i]);
                    }

                    while (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == false)
                    {
                        yield return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    } 
}
```

And using it like this :

```
StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversation(0));
```

Where conversationTrigger is `public ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;`

But it's not working good at all. It's starting the conversation index 0 but then play only the first dialogue sentences twice and then never continue to the next dialogue there are two dialogues in this case. And then it stop.

It should play all the dialogues of the current conversation.
Something in the PlayConversation method is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say your post is long and contains many redundant codes, so I haven't carefully read it, this is a simple reference about making a zoom animation by script.

```
float minScale; // Minimum scale value
float maxScale; // Maximum scale value
Transform target; // Target to scale

void Update()
{
    float scale = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, maxScale - minScale) + minScale;
    target.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
}
```